# Add href attribute to simple_form wrapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, forms, simple-form

I've been trying to write a custom wrapper for my simple_form forms, the problem is that when I try to wrap something with an , the href attribute is not set. The line in question is this:

```
f.use :show_link, :wrap_with => { :tag => 'a', :class => 'toggle-block show-block', href: '#' }
```

:show link is a custom component the just shows some text for the link.

The rendered html is this, as you can see without the href attribute:

```
<a class="toggle-block show-block">Edit currency</a>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Does simple form only accepts HTML global attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
f.use :show_link, :wrap_with => { :tag => 'a', :class => 'toggle-block show-block', :href => '#' }
```

Comment: Doesn't work :-( . As a temporary solution, the attribute href can be set this way, when writing the input in the template: `show_link_html: { ..., href: '#', ... }`